# read and write folder and files to android phone memory

Tags: android, eclipse, storage

I have an app that writes a folder and some files in that folder to external storage (SD).

```
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
{
    File fileDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "AquaInfo");

    if (!fileDir.exists())
    {
        fileDir.mkdirs();
    }
}
```

This is how I create my folder.

The problem now is when I pick my folder and pass it to the internal phone memory. How can I then read and write my data to the folder?

How can I detect if my folder is in the internal or external phone memory?

Edit:

1 - How can I read and write data to internal phone memory using my app? Doe I need some permission or how can i doe that because the code that I have posted only works for external storage.

2 - Imagina that I have a phone withe SD card and save the app folder to the SD card. But now I change my folders location from SD to internal memory. Is it some howe possible to search my folder in both memories (internal and SD) and return my complete path?

Comment: Please explain better.